# BASH Script that reads lsblk and mounts

Tags: bash

I do alot of anti-virus boot scans. What I am trying to do is write a script that will take the output of an lsblk command and then mount all of the disk partitions and all the lvm's possible to directories I create in /mnt. Right now, I do this all manually at the moment and its a bit tedious.

In a perfect world, the script would read the output of lsblk and then create the directories in /mnt based on the disk names (disk sda would lead to the creation of /mnt/sda, and partitions like vg1-lv_root under sda1 would lead to the creation of /sda/sda1/vg1-lv_root) and then mount the created directories accordingly.

To be direct, this is well beyond my scripting abilities. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/162698)

Comment: To increase your chances of getting a useful answer to your question, include (at least an extract from) real `lsblk` output and full details of the complete list of commands that you would want to run given that output.

Comment: If you can provide the output of "**lsblk 2>&1 | grep -v '^loop'**", I can put that together for you.  I don't  work with logical volumes or volume groups, but translating lsblk output into code for what you want **IS** straightforward, as long as we know what you are looking for.

Comment: *"this is well beyond my scripting abilities.** ... A basic is script is just list of commands with the correct arguments. Put one run of your manual process into a file, and then look at where you would need to change options to the commands. This is the purpose of having variables in a script. A simple place to start would be in making variables of any directories that get used more than one time in your process, i.e. `srcDir=/path/to/someDir; targDir=/path/to/differentDir; cd "$srcDir; do_commands .... ; cd $targDir"` . Good luck!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Not a direct answer to your problem**, but a tool to provide information you need in a formatted fashion, the following script can offer some assistance.  It uses **[lsblk](/questions/tagged/lsblk)** at the heart of the OS probe.

If you run it with **no options**, it will provide output that looks like this":

[image]

If you run it with the "**--fstab**" option, it will provide output that looks like this (intended to be used, per your coded preferences, directly in the **/etc/fstab** file):

[image]

**NOTE:**  I use "**/site**" instead of "**/mnt**" or "**/media**" to avoid surprise interventions by the OS for any media that are mounted under those two directories. That is something that you can easily change in the script.

**Script:**

```
#!/bin/sh

#23456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+123456789+
####################################################################################################
###
### $Id: Devices__ReportDiskParts.sh,v 1.7 2021/02/20 02:43:37 root Exp root $
###
### Script to report all partitions that detected by the system.
###
####################################################################################################

TMP=/tmp/`basename $0 ".sh" `.tmp

doFSTAB=0
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        "--fstab" ) doFSTAB=1 ; break ;;
        "--disk" )  lsblk -l -p --output-all | awk  '/[/]dev[/]sd[a-z][0-9]/ { print $0 }' | sort --key=3 | awk '{ printf("%s\n\n", $0 ) ; }' ; exit 0 ;;
        "--pairs" ) lsblk -p -P --output-all | awk  '/[/]dev[/]sd[a-z][0-9]/ { print $0 }' | sort --key=3 | awk '{ printf("%s\n\n", $0 ) ; }' ; exit 0 ;;
        "--raw" )   lsblk -l -p --output-all | sort --key=3 | awk '{ printf("%s\n\n", $0 ) ; }' ; exit 0 ;;
        * )  echo "\n\t Invalid parameter '$1' used on command line.  Only options allowed:  [ --raw | --disk | --fstab ]\n Bye!\n" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "${MROOT}" ]
then
    MROOT="/site" ; export MROOT
fi

pROOT=`df / | grep '/dev/' | awk '{ print $1 }' `
dROOT=`echo ${pROOT} | cut -c1-8 `

# If not terminal redirect comments to stderr.
if [   -t 1 ] ; then echo "\n\t NOTE:  Expected mount point parent for all partitions not on root device => '$MROOT' ..."   ; fi
#if [ ! -t 1 ] ; then echo "\n\t NOTE:  Expected mount point parent for all partitions not on root device => '$MROOT' ..." >&2 ; fi

###
### All available parameters for lsblk  (based on lsblk from util-linux 2.31.1)
###
### In sort order reported by --output-all
###
#1   NAME
#    KNAME
#    MAJ:MIN
#2   FSTYPE
#5   MOUNTPOINT
#ALT3    LABEL
#4   UUID
#    PARTTYPE
#3   PARTLABEL
#    PARTUUID
#    PARTFLAGS
#    RA
#    RO
#    RM
#    HOTPLUG
#    MODEL
#    SERIAL
#6   SIZE
#    STATE
#    OWNER
#    GROUP
#    MODE
#    ALIGNMENT
#    MIN-IO
#    OPT-IO
#    PHY-SEC
#    LOG-SEC
#    ROTA
#    SCHED
#    RQ-SIZE
#    TYPE
#    DISC-ALN
#    DISC-GRAN
#    DISC-MAX
#    DISC-ZERO
#    WSAME
#    WWN
#    RAND
#    PKNAME
#    HCTL
#    TRAN
#7   SUBSYSTEMS
#    REV
#    VENDOR
#    ZONED


#lsblk -l -p -o NAME,FSTYPE,PARTLABEL,UUID,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,SUBSYSTEMS | grep -v 'GRUB' | awk  '/[/]dev[/]sd[a-z][0-9]/ { print $0 }' | sort --key=3 > ${TMP}.lsblk
#cat ${TMP}.lsblk
#cat ${TMP}.lsblk | awk '{ print NF }'

lsblk -P -p -o NAME,FSTYPE,PARTLABEL,UUID,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,SUBSYSTEMS | grep -v 'GRUB' | awk  '/[/]dev[/]sd[a-z][0-9]/ { print $0 }' | sort --key=3 > ${TMP}.lsblk.PAIRS

#cat ${TMP}.lsblk.PAIRS
while read line
do
    eval echo '${line}' | tr ' ' "\n" |
    {   fTYPE=""
        while read data
        do
            eval echo '${data}' | awk -F'"' -v ftype="${fTYPE}" '{
                split($1, vars, "=" ) ;
                Fname=vars[1] ;
#               Fval=vars[2] ;  
                Fval=$2 ;   
                if( Fval == "" ){
                    Fval="null" ;
                } ;
                printf("%s ", Fval) ;
#               printf("%s|%s ", Fname, Fval) ;
            }'
#           case ${data} in
#               FSTYPE* ) fTYPE="USB" ;;
#               * ) ;;
#           esac
        done
    }
    echo ""
done <${TMP}.lsblk.PAIRS >${TMP}.lsblk
#cat ${TMP}.lsblk
#cat ${TMP}.lsblk | awk '{ print NF }'


## WD 4 TB My Book
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#/dev/sdb1 on /site/My Book type exfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,uhelper=udisks2)
### 1,4,9,7,5,18
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
### /dev/sdb1    exfat    My         Book                                   Not_Mounted   /My
#/dev/sdb1  /dev/sdb1  /dev/sdb1    8:17     3.7T   3.7T exfat        6M     0% /site/My Book     My Book  40FA-E56B                            {uuid1} atari  {uuid2} My Book   {uuid3}           128  0  0       1                                                  3.7T         root  disk  brw-rw----         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 mq-deadline       2 part        0        4K       4G         0    0B                       1 /dev/sdb                   block:scsi:usb:pci               none
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
### /dev/sde3    ext4     DB002_F1   {uuid1}   Not_Mounted   /site/DB002_F1
#/dev/sde3  /dev/sde3  /dev/sde3    8:67                 ext4                                                 DB002_F1 {uuid1} {uuid2} dos    {uuid3} DB002_F1  {uuid4}           128  0  0       0                                                279.4G         root  disk  brw-rw----         0   4096      0    4096     512    1 mq-deadline      64 part        0        0B       0B         0    0B 0x50014ee263b2c636    1 /dev/sde                   block:scsi:pci                   none
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
### **** ERROR ****  Not handling 'My Passport' condition correctly
###
### Reporting as follows:
### /dev/sde1    ntfs     My         null                                   Mounted       1.8T                           /media/ericthered/My
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

if [ ${doFSTAB} -eq 0 ]
then
    if [   -t 1 ] ; then echo "\n\t ALL recognized DISK partitions:\n"     ; fi
    #if [ ! -t 1 ] ; then echo "\n\t ALL recognized DISK partitions:\n" >&2 ; fi

    cat ${TMP}.lsblk | awk -v othrPath=${MROOT} -v dROOT="${dROOT}" '{
        if ( $6 == "null" ){
            if ( $2 == "swap" ){
                    printf("%-12s %-8s %-10s %-38s %-13s %-30s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, "Not_Enabled", "[SWAP_OFFLINE]", $7 ) ;  
            }else{
                if ( index($1,dROOT) == 0 ){
                    thatPath=sprintf("%s/%s", othrPath, $3 ) ;
                    printf("%-12s %-8s %-10s %-38s %-13s %-30s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, "Not_Mounted", thatPath, $7 ) ; 
                }else{
                    thatPath=sprintf("/%s", $3 ) ;
                    printf("%-12s %-8s %-10s %-38s %-13s %-30s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, "Not_Mounted", thatPath, $7 ) ; 
                } ;
            } ;
        }else{
                if ( $2 == "swap" ){
                printf("%-12s %-8s %-10s %-38s %-13s %-30s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, "Enabled", $6, $7 ) ;
            }else{
                printf("%-12s %-8s %-10s %-38s %-13s %-30s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, "Mounted", $6, $7 ) ;
            } ;
        } ;
    }'
else
    if [   -t 1 ] ; then echo "\n\t ALL recognized DISK partitions reported in format required to update '/etc/fstab':\n"     ; fi
    #if [ ! -t 1 ] ; then echo "\n\t ALL recognized DISK partitions reported in format required to update '/etc/fstab':\n" >&2 ; fi

    #/dev/sdd1    ext4     DB002_F1   {uuid_2F1}   300G          /site/DB002_F1
    #UUID={uuid_1F1}    /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0   1
    #UUID={uuid_1F2}    /DB001_F2   ext4    nosuid,nodev,nofail,errors=remount-ro   0   2 
    #UUID={uuid_1f3}    none    swap    sw,pri=3    0   0

    ###
    ### FUTURES:   USB options  rw,suid,umask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000
    ###
    cat ${TMP}.lsblk | awk -v othrPath=${MROOT} -v pROOT="${pROOT}" -v dROOT="${dROOT}" '{
         if( index( $0, "usb" ) != 0 ){
            usbPlug="USB_EXTERNAL" ;
         }else{
            usbPlug="INTERNAL" ;
         } ;

        if ( $6 == "null" ){
            if ( $2 == "swap" ){
                if ( $1 == pROOT ) {
                    perms="sw,pri=1" ;
                    seq=1 ;
                }else{
                    perms="sw,pri=2" ;
                    seq=2 ;
                } ;
                if( $4 == "null" ){
                    printf("### %s ###  No value for UUID. No file system on this partition.\n\n", $3 ) ;
                }else{
                    printf("# %-12s %-8s %-10s %-38s %-13s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, "[SWAP]", usbPlug ) ;  
                    printf("UUID=%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s\n\n", $4, "none", $2, perms, "0", seq ) ;
                } ;
            }else{
                if ( $1 == pROOT ) {
                    perms="defaults" ;
                    seq=0 ;
                }else{
                    #perms="nosuid,nodev,nofail,defaults" ;
                    if( usbPlug == "USB_EXTERNAL" ){
                        perms="defaults,nofail,noauto" ;
                    }else{
                        perms="defaults,nofail" ;
                    } ;
                    if ( $1 ~ dROOT ) { seq=1 ; }else{ seq=2 ; } ;
                } ;
                if( $4 == "null" ){
                    printf("### %s ###  No value for UUID. No file system on this partition.\n\n", $3 ) ;
                }else{
                    if ( index($1,dROOT) == 0 ){
                        printf("# %-12s %-8s %-10s %-38s %-13s %s/%s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, othrPath, $3, usbPlug ) ; 
                        printf("UUID=%s \t%s/%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s\n\n", $4, othrPath, $3, $2, perms, "0", seq ) ;
                    }else{
                        printf("# %-12s %-8s %-10s %-38s %-13s /%s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $3, usbPlug ) ; 
                        printf("UUID=%s \t/%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s\n\n", $4, $3, $2, perms, "0", seq ) ;
                    } ;
                } ;
            } ;
        }else{
                if ( $2 == "swap" ){

                if ( $1 == pROOT ) {
                    perms="sw,pri=1" ;
                    seq=1 ;
                }else{
                    perms="sw,pri=2" ;
                    seq=2 ;
                } ;
                if( $4 == "null" ){
                    printf("### %s ###  No value for UUID. No file system on this partition.\n\n", $3 ) ;
                }else{
                    printf("# %-12s %-8s %-10s %-38s %-13s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, usbPlug ) ;
                    printf("UUID=%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s\n\n", $4, "none", $2, perms, "0", seq ) ;
                };
            }else{

                if ( $1 == pROOT ) {
                    perms="defaults" ;
                    seq=0 ;
                }else{
                    #perms="nosuid,nodev,nofail,defaults" ;
                    if( usbPlug == "USB_EXTERNAL" ){
                        perms="defaults,nofail,noauto" ;
                    }else{
                        perms="defaults,nofail" ;
                    } ;
                    if ( $1 ~ dROOT ) { seq=1 ; }else{ seq=2 ; } ;
                } ;
                if( $4 == "null" ){
                    printf("### %s ###  No value for UUID. No file system on this partition.\n\n", $3 ) ;
                }else{
                    printf("# %-12s %-8s %-10s %-38s %-13s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, usbPlug ) ;
                    printf("UUID=%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s \t%s\n\n", $4, $6, $2, perms, "0", seq ) ;
                };
            } ;
        } ;
    }'
fi

# Other command format for other properties related to partitions:
#   lsblk -o NAME,ALIGNMENT,MIN-IO,OPT-IO,PHY-SEC,LOG-SEC,ROTA,SCHED,RQ-SIZE,RA,WSAME

# Other option which is not as complete:
#   blkid -o list

if [   -t 1 ] ; then echo "\n\t Done.  [`basename $0 `]\n"     ; fi
#if [ ! -t 1 ] ; then echo "\t Done.  [`basename $0 `]\n" >&2 ; fi

rm -f ${TMP}.*

exit 0
exit 0
exit 0
```